# Tensor product for binary numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I'm working on an FPGA project where I need to calculate tensor product between two binary numbers. This is to be used to calculate CRC values. I was referring to this paper from IEEE. "[Fast parallel CRC algorithm and implementation on a configurable processor](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/997161/)"

According to this paper, I need to calculate the "product" of this expression;

1011 $\otimes$ 1001

Is this tensor product or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might have better luck on the [EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site

Comment: I am not where I can get access to the paper.  If it is not defined, please quote the first time it is used for context.  I think I have seen that for bitwise XOR

Comment: In the paper, it has mentioned that $\otimes$ is Galois Field multiplication.

Comment: If $\otimes$ is being used as the product operation in a finite field, then it doesn't mean "tensor product".

Comment: Also, describing multiplication in a finite field of characteristic 2 as a "product of binary numbers" (or similarly, involving "carry free multiplication") is niche jargon; AFAIK it's only really used by a subset of computer programmers.